# Cognito get list user in group with Warrant

Tags: flask, python-3.6, amazon-cognito

I just try with AWS cognito for authentication my web application.

I am using Warrant library https://github.com/capless/warrant
I have many users which belong to my group (Ex: G1, G2, G3)

However, I cannot find the way to get list of users for specific group. 
Can anyone tell me how to get list users in specific group?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just passed by the same situation as you, because I'm using warrant to. The problem is that warrant is an high level library, so it doesn't have capacity to manipulate all features that cognito can provide.

So, if you can try to solve this problem without using warrant, my solution is to use boto3 identity provider api, an low level feature that works with various usefull features of cognito.

[Check these low level functions in AWS API documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_users_in_group)

So, using these functionalities, I made the code bellow to list all users at some group:

```
import boto3

cognito_cl = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

res = cognito_cl.list_users_in_group(
    UserPoolId=<some_pool_id>,
    GroupName=<some_group_name>
)

group_users = res.get('Users', 'empty')
```

Then, if you access group_users variable, you can see the list of all users in this group, just like all of their attributes.

Hope that I have helped you even after so long.